# In .bat file set variable to use in MySql command in same .bat file

Tags: mysql, shell, batch-file

If I have a .bat file where I want to execute a mysql command as follows:

```
mysql -u root -pPass DBName -e "SELECT * FROM DBName.TableName WHERE field==something"
```

How can I set a variable before the mysql command and then use it in the select query?

For example, the .bat file will look like this:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off
set myvar=value1
mysql -u root -pPass DBName -e "SELECT * FROM DBName.TableName WHERE ID==!myvar!"
```

So that the select query uses 'value1' for the comparison in the 'ID' column.

Thank you

Comment: use %myvar% to get the saved variable

Comment: @PaulF, definitely not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: So the '%' sign doesn't work. I assume because of the EnableDelayedExpansion thing that I got from somewhere else. In my actual query I am using a date field for the WHERE part, so there is apostrophes around the variable also now. Something like "SELECT * FROM DBName.TableName WHERE datetime BETWEEN '!myvar!' AND '!myvar2!'".